# Distribution combinations of an amount (integers only) over different buckets

Tags: r

Imagine one has 5 buckets (1 - 5) and that to each of these buckets an (integer) value is assigned. E.g.

```
> bucket = 1:5
> value = c(14, 12, 9, 20, 7)
> data.frame(bucket, value)
  bucket value
1      1    14
2      2    12
3      3     9
4      4    20
5      5     7
```

Then, one is asked to increase the values of the buckets with a total of 3 (only increases with integers allowed). There are several ways of distributing a total of 3 (only increases with integers allowed) over these buckets.

Is there a function in R that gives all possible distributions of a total of 3 over the 5 buckets?

More specifically, something like:

```
  distr1 distr2 distr3 distr4 distr5 distr6 ....
1      3      2      2      2      2      1 ....
2      0      1      0      0      0      2 ....
3      0      0      1      0      0      0 ....
4      0      0      0      1      0      0 ....
5      0      0      0      0      1      0 ....
```

I looked into `combn()` and `expand.grid()`, but those did not seem the appropriate functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possibility, with `expand.grid`, probably not the most elegant though:

```
n_buckets <- 5
increase <- 3

foo <- do.call(
  expand.grid, 
  replicate(increase, seq_len(n_buckets), simplify = FALSE)
)

res <- apply(foo, 1, function(x) {
  sapply(seq_len(n_buckets), function(y) sum(y == x))
})


#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
# [1,]    3    2    2    2    2    2    1    1    1     1     2
# [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    1    2    1    1     1     0
# [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0     0     1
# [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1     0     0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     1     0
#      [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
# [1,]     1     1     1     1     2     1     1     1     1
# [2,]     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
# [3,]     1     2     1     1     0     0     1     0     0
# [4,]     0     0     1     0     1     1     1     2     1
# [5,]     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
#
# ...
```

*Note:* Just noticed there is redundancy in my answer, due to the fact that I distinguish between putting `a` in bucket `1` and `b` in bucket `2`, and `b` in bucket `1` and `a` in bucket `2`. You still get all the possibilities...

**EDIT**: Removing the duplicates:

```
res[, !duplicated(res, MARGIN = 2)]

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
# [1,]    3    2    2    2    2    1    1    1    1     1     1
# [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    2    1    1    1     0     0
# [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     2     1
# [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    0     0     1
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    1     0     0
#      [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21]
# [1,]     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [2,]     0     0     0     0     3     2     2     2     1     1
# [3,]     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     2     1
# [4,]     0     2     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
# [5,]     1     0     1     2     0     0     0     1     0     0
#      [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31]
# [1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [2,]     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
# [3,]     1     0     0     0     3     2     2     1     1     1
# [4,]     0     2     1     0     0     1     0     2     1     0
# [5,]     1     0     1     2     0     0     1     0     1     2
#      [,32] [,33] [,34] [,35]
# [1,]     0     0     0     0
# [2,]     0     0     0     0
# [3,]     0     0     0     0
# [4,]     3     2     1     0
# [5,]     0     1     2     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Chipping in as well:

First we create all possible combinations of the values 0-3 (`invec`) and then we select only those wich sum up to 3 over all buckets using `rowSums`:

```
incvec <- 0:3

allDists <- expand.grid(b1=incvec,b2=incvec,b3=incvec,b4=incvec,b5=incvec)

finDists <- allDists[rowSums(allDists) == 3,]

> head(finDists)
   b1 b2 b3 b4 b5
4   3  0  0  0  0
7   2  1  0  0  0
10  1  2  0  0  0
13  0  3  0  0  0
19  2  0  1  0  0
22  1  1  1  0  0
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grid.expand` to determine which bins can be called

```
I <- expand.grid(1:5,1:5,1:5)
```

Then make a `table` of each row, convert to `data.frame`, `spread` to wide format then convert to `data.frame` using `map_df`

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
dist_df <- map_df(1:nrow(I), ~ as.data.frame(table(unlist(I[.x,]))) %>% spread(Var1,Freq)) %>%
             replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

#### Output

```
    1 2 3 4 5
1   3 0 0 0 0
2   2 1 0 0 0
3   2 0 1 0 0
4   2 0 0 1 0
5   2 0 0 0 1
```

Notice that my output should be read rowwise

Comment: I don't use the library that provides `map_df`, but thanks for providing this solution.